# The issuer '(null)' is invalid

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, microsoft-identity-web

> Issues with authenticate to a protected webapi controller

Comment: Which identity provider you have used now? Microsoft Entra ID?or other identity provider. Besides, please post more details about your program.cs codes

Comment: @BrandoZhang I have utilized MS Identity successfully in the past. However, this issue is occurring with all the latest libraries.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Dear @Community bot. You have no soul.